# How can I make unity to search a program, say from my home directory?

Tags: unity

I'd like to see the program icon when I type the program name into the search bar, and when I click it, the program will be launched.

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 0):

Use Synapse for this task. You can search files and applications with it.

Comment: This does not answer the question in any way. The OP asks to see the icon of the application, *not* install new applications. Also, Synaptic does not launch applications or show their icons. It is but a package manager.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS  Still may not be a good answer, but 'synapse' is a launcher (as opposed to 'synaptic').

Comment: @belacqua Apologies for my ignorance,